# R aplication without internet

Tags: r

I want to develop an aplication with witch it creates a file with information in my computer.
I have searched, but the last option that I have found is to use Shiny package. The last problem is that I don't want that my aplication uses internet.
Is there any package that do that?

Comment: http://theautomatic.net/2018/07/11/manipulate-files-r/ ?! Or in general:  "<language> file manipluation"

Comment: shiny does not require internet.